# How to determine if a test was done how many years consecutively for individuals using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

how do i determine if a certain population has met the conditions of having a test done consecutively for a few years based on their first test date? A example dataset can be found below. I'm thinking of using dataset 1 as df1 and Dataset 2 as df2 but my problem is I'm not sure how to use the first date of collection for different IDs to minus the different collection date of the same IDs?

Dataset 1:

| ID | Date of Collection | Test Done |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My-ID 00001 | 10/05/2016 | 1A |
| My-ID 00001 | 10/01/2017 | 1A |
| My-ID 00001 | 23/01/2018 | 1A |
| My-ID 00001 | 18/04/2019 | 1A |
| My-ID 00001 | 30/04/2020 | 1A |
| My-ID 00002 | 30/09/2015 | 1A |
| My-ID 00002 | 31/05/2016 | 1A |
| My-ID 00002 | 31/05/2017 | 1A |
| My-ID 00003 | 31/05/2017 | 1A |

Dataset 2:

| ID | Test Done | Result | Date of Collection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| My-ID 00001 | 1A | 50 | 10/05/2016 |
| My-ID 00002 | 1A | 75 | 30/09/2015 |

Desired Outcome:

| ID | Date of Collection | Test Done | Year since first collection date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| My-ID 00001 | 10/05/2016 | 1A | 0 |
| My-ID 00001 | 10/01/2017 | 1A | 1 |
| My-ID 00001 | 23/01/2018 | 1A | 2 |
| My-ID 00001 | 18/04/2019 | 1A | 3 |
| My-ID 00001 | 30/04/2020 | 1A | 4 |
| My-ID 00002 | 30/09/2015 | 1A | 0 |
| My-ID 00002 | 31/05/2016 | 1A | 1 |

Comment: Not sure why the table is not showing here but it's showing on my edits......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible use first year per groups substract it grom first values per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df1['Date of Collection'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date of Collection'], dayfirst=True)

y = df1['Date of Collection'].dt.year
df1['Year since first collection date'] = y.sub(y.groupby(df['ID']).transform('first'))
print (df1)
            ID Date of Collection Test Done  Year since first collection date
0  My-ID 00001         2016-05-10        1A                                 0
1  My-ID 00001         2017-01-10        1A                                 1
2  My-ID 00001         2018-01-23        1A                                 2
3  My-ID 00001         2019-04-18        1A                                 3
4  My-ID 00001         2020-04-30        1A                                 4
5  My-ID 00002         2015-09-30        1A                                 0
6  My-ID 00002         2016-05-31        1A                                 1
7  My-ID 00003         2017-05-31        1A                                 0
```

If need processing first values from `df2` add left join before solution with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1['Date of Collection'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date of Collection'], dayfirst=True)
df2['Date of First Collection'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date of First Collection'], dayfirst=True)

y = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID','Test Done'], how='left')['Date of First Collection'].dt.year
df1['Year since first collection date'] = y.sub(y.groupby(df['ID']).transform('first'))
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but got an error where it stated "The Above exception was the direction cause of the following exception, Key Error: "Date of Collection". I've edited the dataset to look more similar like how my dataset is looking like.

Comment: @AlexBraningston - I used `df` instead `df1`, now it should working